# Do-While Statement for Receipt (C#)

Tags: c#

So, as the title suggests, I am trying to use a Do-While statement in C# to make a receipt. What I wish to happen is, when an order is placed, the Do-While statement will be able to see the items purchased, and the total that the purchased items should come to.

So, for example, I have two espressos that cost £2.20, a hot chocolate that costs £2.75 and a mocha that also costs £2.75.

I want the receipt to look something like:

Espresso x2 - £4.40
Hot Chocolate x1 - £2.75
Mocha x1 - £2.75

Of course, if say the order had two mocha instead of one, and maybe an extra item, like three americano for £2.50 it would look like:

Espresso x2 - £4.40
Hot Chocolate x1 - £2.75
Mocha x2 - £5.50
Americano x3 - £7.50

I understand how to do a simple Do-While code, but with what I am attempting (if it can be done) has be stuck and I have been struggling for a while now.

Any help would be appreciated.

My Code Currently looks like this, to get the calculations working:

```
namespace While_Receipt
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        decimal priceespresso, totalespresso, pricefilter, totalfilter, priceCappuccino, totalCappuccino, priceAmericano,
            totalAmericano, priceLatte, totalLatte, priceMocha, totalMocha, priceHotChocolate, totalHotChocolate,
            priceIceCoffee, totalIceCoffee, priceExtra, totalExtra, TotalOverall;


        int quantityespresso, quantityfilter, quantitiyCappuccino, quantityAmericano, quantityLatte, quantitiyMocha,
            quantitiyHotChocolate, quantityIceCoffee, quantityExtra;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
private void btnTotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            priceespresso = Convert.ToDecimal(txtEspressoPrice.Text);
            quantityespresso = Convert.ToInt32(txtEspressoMultiply.Text);
            totalespresso = priceespresso * quantityespresso;
            lblResults.Text = Convert.ToString(totalespresso);

            pricefilter = Convert.ToDecimal(txtFilterPrice.Text);
            quantityfilter = Convert.ToInt32(txtFilterMultiply.Text);
            totalfilter = pricefilter * quantityfilter;
            lblFilterResults.Text = Convert.ToString(totalfilter);

            priceCappuccino = Convert.ToDecimal(txtCappuccinoPrice.Text);
            quantitiyCappuccino = Convert.ToInt32(txtAmericanoMultiply.Text);
            totalCappuccino = priceCappuccino * quantitiyCappuccino;
            lblCappuccinoResults.Text = Convert.ToString(totalCappuccino);

            priceAmericano = Convert.ToDecimal(txtAmericanoPrice.Text);
            quantityAmericano = Convert.ToInt32(txtCappuccinoMultiply.Text);
            totalAmericano = priceAmericano * quantityAmericano;
            lblAmericanoResults.Text = Convert.ToString(totalAmericano);

            priceLatte = Convert.ToDecimal(txtLattePrice.Text);
            quantityLatte = Convert.ToInt32(txtLatteMultiply.Text);
            totalLatte = priceLatte * quantityLatte;
            lblLatteResults.Text = Convert.ToString(totalLatte);

            priceMocha = Convert.ToDecimal(txtMochaPrice.Text);
            quantitiyMocha = Convert.ToInt32(txtMochaMultiply.Text);
            totalMocha = priceMocha * quantitiyMocha;
            lblMochaResults.Text = Convert.ToString(totalMocha);

            priceHotChocolate = Convert.ToDecimal(txtHotChocolatePrice.Text);
            quantitiyHotChocolate = Convert.ToInt32(txtHotChocolateMultiply.Text);
            totalHotChocolate = priceHotChocolate * quantitiyHotChocolate;
            lblHotChocolateResults.Text = Convert.ToString(totalHotChocolate);

            priceIceCoffee = Convert.ToDecimal(txtIceCoffeePrice.Text);
            quantityIceCoffee = Convert.ToInt32(txtIcedCoffeeMultiply.Text);
            totalIceCoffee = priceIceCoffee * quantityIceCoffee;
            lblIcedCoffeeResults.Text = Convert.ToString(totalIceCoffee);

            priceExtra = Convert.ToDecimal(txtExtra.Text);
            quantityExtra = Convert.ToInt32(txtExtraMultiply.Text);
            totalExtra = priceExtra * quantityExtra;
            txtExtraResults.Text = Convert.ToString(totalExtra);

            TotalOverall = totalespresso + totalfilter + totalCappuccino + totalAmericano + totalLatte
            + totalMocha + totalHotChocolate + totalIceCoffee + totalExtra;
            lblTotalOverall.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalOverall);
          }

        private void lstResults_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The fields you defined are very suitable for a class. Try to combine data which are related in classes. There are many buildin functions to calculate the sum of multiple products etc.

Comment: Recognize commonality.  You have pairs of textboxes, that could be a single UserControl with a Price and a Multiplier property.  You have several pairs, that could be tracked with a `List<YourControl>` and arranged with a FlowLayoutPanel.  Now it just takes a `foreach` to calculate the total and it will work for any number of items.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario there is not much you can do with a do-while cycle. You could check each quantity one by one with an `if`, to see whether they are greater than 0, and when they are, then to output them onto the receipt.

I would recommend to you some learning (from a C# book you find). First to learn about classes, to create a class for a receipt detail, which would have properties for the product being sold, the quantity, the price and the value.

Then you should learn about collections, to put the products which are being sold into a collection.

You will be able to display the content of the collection in a grid control or a ListView.

After these steps, you will be able to go through the content of the collection with a cycle (instead of the do-while cycle with a `foreach` cycle), and output those items to the receipt.